# scanning until EOF in c

Tags: c

I am writing a decryption program and I need to scan in an unknown number of strings and decode each string as it is entered.  The program must end once it reaches EOF.

I am having difficulty getting the program to end.  when I scan in the first char in the string in my while loop condition statement, it is doing this but when I scan in the actual string bellow the condition statement the string is missing the first char. Should I scan in the first char and then somehow put that char at the beginning of the string?

**How do I properly test for EOF in my situation?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char code[300];

    while(scanf("%c", &code[0])!=EOF)
    {
        scanf("%s", code);

        for(i=0; i<strlen(code); i++)
        {
            decrypt message one char at a time
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's exactly wrong with `while(scanf("%s", code) != EOF)`?

Comment: @n.m. What's wrong with it is that EOF isn't the right test ... doesn't anyone read the documentation?

Comment: @JimBalter One idea at a time please. It is not the right test in general, but OK for `%s`.

Comment: "One idea at a time please" -- Such nonsense. You asked what's wrong and I answered. "but OK for %s" -- Wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (scanf("%s", code) == 1)
{
    // no need for second scanf call
    ...
```

Comment: Works great now.  Thanks Jim.

Comment: Note to @Lipovlan: your suggested edit is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (scanf("%c", &code[0]) == 1)
{   scanf("%s", &code[1]);
    ...
```

Comment: Read the `scanf` documentation ... EOF is not the right test. And why two scanf calls?

Comment: @JimBalter fixed test for EOF

Comment: No, that's worse... Ok, glad to see you fixed it, but I already answered this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `scanf` at all is a bad idea for this particular problem.

```
while(scanf("%c", &code[0])!=EOF)
```

This `scanf` call reads a single character. Just use `getchar()`.

```
scanf("%s", code);

for(i=0; i<strlen(code); i++)
{
    decrypt message one char at a time
}
```

The `scanf` call can read arbitrarily many characters (after skipping whitespace; are you sure you want to skip whitespace?). That means that if there are too many characters to be read from `stdin`, you have a buffer overflow, one that you can't avoid unless you have complete control over what appears on `stdin`.

You then loop over the `code` array, calling `strlen()` for each character you process. Since `strlen()` generally has to scan from the beginning of the array to the terminating `'\0'`, this is inefficient. *If* you need to traverse the characters of a string, either call `strlen()` once and save the value, or look for the terminating `'\0'` character.

But you're just processing one character at a time, so just *read* one character at a time:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    /* process a character */
}
```

Don't worry about reading one character at a time being inefficient; buffering will take care of that.